# error C2664: 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [58]' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++

guys whay i have this to error and how i can fix that?!
but before that i say i searched in the net and find a solution for my problem such as:
 the properties, and navigate to Configuration Properties > General. Switch Character Set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". 
but also i have same error?!!

The error's:

```
Error   7   error C2664: 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [58]' to 'LPCSTR'   

Error   8   error C2664: 'int std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::compare(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
```

and my code is:

```
#include "StdInc.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<TlHelp32.h>

using std::ifstream;
using std::string;
using std::getline;
using std::ios;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::fixed;
using std::left;
using std::right;
using std::showpoint;
using std::cin;

class check {

public :


void check_seta () {

    ifstream cfgm2("finfin.cfg",ios::in);

    string cfgLine;

    while (getline(cfgm2,cfgLine)) {

        if (string::npos != cfgLine.find("seta mamamia")){

             if (cfgLine.at(19) == '0'){

                 MessageBox(NULL , L"lol not do that",NULL,MB_ICONERROR); 

                 std::wstring Processname(L"mod.exe");

                 DWORD ProcessId = FindProcessId(Processname);

                 HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE ,ProcessId);

                 TerminateProcess(pHandle,0);

                 CloseHandle(pHandle);
             }
             break;
        }

    }
}

DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
    {
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

    HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if ( processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    return 0;

    Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
    if ( !processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile) )
    {
        CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while ( Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo) )
    {
        if ( !processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile) )
        {
            CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
            return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
    return 0;
}
};
```

Comment: MBCS is not Unicode.  MessageBoxA() is the non-Unicode version of the function.  You can declare the array as TEXT() or _T().

Answer (score 4):

In the project settings you did not select Unicode. So you have the narrow sharacter version of the WIN32 API. MessageBox maps to MessageBoxA, and the process info structure has LPCSTR in it.   If you change the setting those become MessageBoxW and  LPCWSTR, and the code will compile (or you get other errors elsewhere).

If you mean to use that the A versions, use char instead of wchar_t, string instead of wstring, "xxx" instead of L"xxxx" all around.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wide string literals (`L"..."`), so you must actually use the *Unicode* character set in the Project settings you mention. This will define `_UNICODE` and make all Windows function-name macros expand to the wide-character variants (suffix `W`).

Or, preferably, if you know you want to use wide strings, just call the wide-char versions directly. That is, use `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBox`, etc. for other char-width-specific functions.

Comment: @artines Would you point out on which line the error occurs, and give the complete error (you didn't include the part where it lists the actual template arguments involved)?

Comment: with adding W to  MessageBoxW(NULL , L"lol not do that",NULL,MB_ICONERROR);  this line problem solved...but i have to 2 more error on line 74 that:     if ( !processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile) ) and line 82:   if ( !processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile) )   and i adde error message in first post :Error   8   error C2664: ....

Comment: @artines You seem to be doing more or less random changes to your code without understanding the issue. This will not get you anywhere. Read up something on what the suffixes `A` and `W` on WinAPI functions mean, and how they interact with `char + std::string` vs. `wchar_t + std::wstring`. You can start [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties in Visual Studio, go to Configuration Settings > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions and make sure UNICODE; is defined. That fixed a similar error for me.